# mysQL to IBM Data Connect

Tags: mysql, dataconnect

I setup my first local mysql and tables and want to push these tables via IBM Data Connect to an other location. Gateway/Connection works fine, but Data Connect doesn't show the tables at refine step.  Is it because of timeout or schemas? Where can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me for Federated tables. Those Schemas did not even appear on the list. 
Furthermore, it seems to be still improving, as depending on the browser you use, it freezes searching for the tables, or show blank, but when refreshing it seems to work (when it is not Federeated)

Hope this helps. thanks